# Django - Grouping with multiple values works on first item

Tags: python, django

When I want to make a query with multiple fields in "values()" and only one field in "annotate()", the grouping is applied only on the FIRST item on "values()".

Here my code:

```
class filterManager():
        '''
        Gestion global des filtre pour le requeting
        '''
        def __init__(self):
                self._datas = {}

        def setFilter(self,key,value):
                '''
                Mise en place d'un champs de filtre
                '''
                self._datas[key] = value
                return 1
        def getItem(self,key):
                '''
                Récupération d'un unique champs du filtre
                '''
                return self._datas[key]

        def getFilter(self):
                '''
                Récupération du filtre entier
                '''
                return self._datas

myFilter = filterManager()
myFilter.setFilter("rcad_date__range", ['2017-03-12','2017-03-19'])
myFilter.setFilter("rcad_type__in", [0])
myFilter.setFilter("rcad_status__in", [1,2])

for item in reportingCentreonAlarmsDaily.objects\
.values("rcad_date","rcad_type","rcad_status")\
.annotate(total = Sum('rcad_count') )\
.filter(**myFilter.getFilter()):
    print item
```

It gives :

```
{'rcad_date': datetime.date(2017, 3, 12), 'rcad_status': 1, 'total': 5610, 'rcad_type': 0}
{'rcad_date': datetime.date(2017, 3, 13), 'rcad_status': 1, 'total': 6354, 'rcad_type': 0}
{'rcad_date': datetime.date(2017, 3, 14), 'rcad_status': 1, 'total': 4774, 'rcad_type': 0}
{'rcad_date': datetime.date(2017, 3, 15), 'rcad_status': 1, 'total': 4943, 'rcad_type': 0}
{'rcad_date': datetime.date(2017, 3, 16), 'rcad_status': 1, 'total': 4896, 'rcad_type': 0}
{'rcad_date': datetime.date(2017, 3, 17), 'rcad_status': 1, 'total': 4759, 'rcad_type': 0}
{'rcad_date': datetime.date(2017, 3, 18), 'rcad_status': 1, 'total': 3718, 'rcad_type': 0}
{'rcad_date': datetime.date(2017, 3, 19), 'rcad_status': 1, 'total': 3788, 'rcad_type': 0}
```

As you could guess.. it's not OK :(

What I want is:

```
SELECT 
rcad_date,rcad_status, SUM(rcad_count) 
FROM reporting_centreon_alarms_daily  
WHERE rcad_date BETWEEN '2017-03-12' AND '2017-03-19' 
AND rcad_status IN (1,2) 
AND rcad_type IN (0) 
GROUP BY rcad_date,rcad_status;
+------------+-------------+-----------------+
| rcad_date  | rcad_status | SUM(rcad_count) |
+------------+-------------+-----------------+
| 2017-03-12 |           1 |            1965 |
| 2017-03-12 |           2 |            3645 |
| 2017-03-13 |           1 |            2483 |
| 2017-03-13 |           2 |            3871 |
| 2017-03-14 |           1 |            2166 |
| 2017-03-14 |           2 |            2608 |
| 2017-03-15 |           1 |            2179 |
| 2017-03-15 |           2 |            2764 |
| 2017-03-16 |           1 |            2271 |
| 2017-03-16 |           2 |            2625 |
| 2017-03-17 |           1 |            2200 |
| 2017-03-17 |           2 |            2559 |
| 2017-03-18 |           1 |            1613 |
| 2017-03-18 |           2 |            2105 |
| 2017-03-19 |           1 |            1705 |
| 2017-03-19 |           2 |            2083 |
+------------+-------------+-----------------+
```

But this is why I obtain:

```
SELECT rcad_date, rcad_status, SUM(rcad_count) 
FROM reporting_centreon_alarms_daily 
WHERE rcad_date BETWEEN '2017-03-12' AND '2017-03-19' 
AND rcad_status IN (1,2) 
AND rcad_type IN (0) 
GROUP BY rcad_date;
+------------+-------------+-----------------+
| rcad_date  | rcad_status | SUM(rcad_count) |
+------------+-------------+-----------------+
| 2017-03-12 |           1 |            5610 |
| 2017-03-13 |           1 |            6354 |
| 2017-03-14 |           1 |            4774 |
| 2017-03-15 |           1 |            4943 |
| 2017-03-16 |           1 |            4896 |
| 2017-03-17 |           1 |            4759 |
| 2017-03-18 |           1 |            3718 |
| 2017-03-19 |           1 |            3788 |
+------------+-------------+-----------------+
```

So I don't understand my mistake. I have read many topics about the grouping in Django with ORM but and query seems OK... :/

Could you help me? :)

Thank you in advance for you help!

Answer (score 0):

I partially fix it by adding an extra before value:

```
.extra({"rcad_date":"DATE(rcad_date)"})\
```

It gives :

```
{'rcad_date': datetime.date(2017, 3, 12), 'rcad_status': 1, 'total': 1965, 'rcad_type': 0}
{'rcad_date': datetime.date(2017, 3, 12), 'rcad_status': 2, 'total': 3645, 'rcad_type': 0}
{'rcad_date': datetime.date(2017, 3, 13), 'rcad_status': 1, 'total': 2483, 'rcad_type': 0}
{'rcad_date': datetime.date(2017, 3, 13), 'rcad_status': 2, 'total': 3871, 'rcad_type': 0}
{'rcad_date': datetime.date(2017, 3, 14), 'rcad_status': 1, 'total': 2166, 'rcad_type': 0}
{'rcad_date': datetime.date(2017, 3, 14), 'rcad_status': 2, 'total': 2608, 'rcad_type': 0}
{'rcad_date': datetime.date(2017, 3, 15), 'rcad_status': 1, 'total': 2179, 'rcad_type': 0}
{'rcad_date': datetime.date(2017, 3, 15), 'rcad_status': 2, 'total': 2764, 'rcad_type': 0}
{'rcad_date': datetime.date(2017, 3, 16), 'rcad_status': 1, 'total': 2271, 'rcad_type': 0}
{'rcad_date': datetime.date(2017, 3, 16), 'rcad_status': 2, 'total': 2625, 'rcad_type': 0}
{'rcad_date': datetime.date(2017, 3, 17), 'rcad_status': 1, 'total': 2200, 'rcad_type': 0}
{'rcad_date': datetime.date(2017, 3, 17), 'rcad_status': 2, 'total': 2559, 'rcad_type': 0}
{'rcad_date': datetime.date(2017, 3, 18), 'rcad_status': 1, 'total': 1613, 'rcad_type': 0}
{'rcad_date': datetime.date(2017, 3, 18), 'rcad_status': 2, 'total': 2105, 'rcad_type': 0}
{'rcad_date': datetime.date(2017, 3, 19), 'rcad_status': 1, 'total': 1705, 'rcad_type': 0}
{'rcad_date': datetime.date(2017, 3, 19), 'rcad_status': 2, 'total': 2083, 'rcad_type': 0}
```

It's what I expected but.... why without extra, it doesn't work?